# Helm lookup can't find metadata in secret

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

I want to use the "Helm lookup" function to achieve the following use-case:

-My Helmchart deploys various SealedSecrets containing the credentials of databases

-The deployed sealedSecret is picked up by the sealedSecret Operator (by Bitnami) and deploys a regular secret

-In the same Helmchart I want to use "Helm lookup" to get these decrypted credentials deploy another custom resource for another Operator.

-No matter how often I read the official documentation I simply get no data returned.

Here is my simplified current attempt:

```
{{ $secretObject := (lookup "v1" "Secret" $instance.namespace $secretDataSource.name).items }} 
    - name: {{- $secretObject.metadata.name }}
      [...]
```

($instance.namespace is the namespace everything is deployed in)
($secretDataSource.name is the name of the secret)

Am I missing something obvious?

```
{{ $secretObject := (lookup "v1" "Secret" $instance.namespace $secretDataSource.name).metadata.name }} 
    - name: {{- $secretObject }}
      [...]
```

```
{{ $secretObject := (lookup "v1" "Secret" $instance.namespace $secretDataSource.name).items }} 
    - name: {{- $secretObject.metadata.name }}
      [...]
```